# What is the best practice to merge repos from different openshift apps/accounts?

Tags: django, git, openshift

I have an `openshift app` running on my development account, now I want to merge this repo into my teammate's account that should handle the production.

The development app has the 1.0 version of the app as the runtime repo, the production app has just a brand new installation on another account.
I would like to `git merge` the development repo into the production repo, into the other app in the other account. 
I have already administration privileges on the production one.
I'm not a big expert in practical git but I know quite well the command for daily tasks, so a little guidelines would be appreciated.

Simpler: *I have to move an app from an openshift account(A) to another openshift account(B).*
*How can I merge the repository in A with the repository in B?*

<strike>What is the best `deployment workflow` to do that?</strike>

What are the git commands I have to run to make the repoA to be, first, a repoB's branch and then to merge it with repo(B)?

Comment: I'm more than a little confused by the wording of your question. Can you clarify exactly what it is you're trying to merge and why? There's a lot of different terms used for different repos here.

Comment: I have to merge a repo from an openshift account/app with a repo into another openshift account/app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other repository as another remote (upstream maybe?) and then do a git rebase to pull that code into your repository.  See this article for more information: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1006-sync-new-git-repo-with-your-own-existing-git-repo

Comment: can you be more precise and write down some sequence of commands, please

Comment: It would be similar to this, but use the git repo's of two separate gears: https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1006-sync-new-git-repo-with-your-own-existing-git-repo